# PATINDEX pattern to replace character that is *not* first character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to paritally 'leet-ify' a word, by taking a single character from a pre-defined set of replacable characters, and replacing it with a number/special character that resembles the letter being replaced. I *don't* want to replace the *first* character though.

Earlier I get a word that I've ensured has at least one letter after the first that is within the set of replaceable letters, and place it in the `@Word` variable. I then use the following to replace one letter. (Using 'loveable' as an example)

```
DECLARE @Word varchar(8) = 'lovable';
DECLARE @ReplaceChar varchar(1);


SET @ReplaceChar = SUBSTRING(@Word,PATINDEX('[a-z][abeilost]',@Word)+1,1);
SET @ReplaceChar = 
    (SELECT CASE @ReplaceChar
            WHEN 'a' THEN '@'
            WHEN 'b' THEN '8'
            WHEN 'e' THEN '3'
            WHEN 'i' THEN '!'
            WHEN 'l' THEN '1'
            WHEN 'o' THEN '0'
            WHEN 's' THEN '$'
            WHEN 't' THEN '+'
        END 
    );

SET @Word = STUFF(@Word,PATINDEX('[a-z][abeilost]',@Word)+1,1,@ReplaceChar);
```

As I understand it, `PATINDEX` should be finding the starting location of the first any-letter-followed-by-a-matching-letter string, and `SUBSTRING`/`STUFF` explicitly adds 1 to that number before collecting or replacing, so I should never get 'lovable' changed to '1oveable'... But that's what I'm getting. What am I missing?

To clarify expected results:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| loveable | l0veable |
| give | g1ve |
| shelter | sh3lter |
| grams | gr@ms |
| phrygian | phryg!an |

Comment: Starting with v2017 there is [TRANSLATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Try something along `SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(@word,1),TRANSLATE(SUBSTRING(@word,2,8000),'abeilost','@83!10$+'));`. With your input `loveable` this will return `l0v3@813`.

Comment: Super useful usually, but not quite what I’m after this time: I only want to translate one character: the first non-first-letter that matches candidate letters. All the rest of the word should remain as-is. So desired output for loveable would be `l0veable`

Comment: well, you can combine this with STUFF() and PATINDEX()... Cut off the first, find the first occurance, translate this single character and stuff it into the position found.

Comment: True. Definitely more elegant than my case statement. Which itself could have simply been `SELECT @ReplaceChar =…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our talk in the comments above I'd suggest this approach:

```
DECLARE @Word varchar(8) = 'truth';

DECLARE @toBeReplaced VARCHAR(10)='abeilost';
DECLARE @replaceWith VARCHAR(10)='@83!10$+';

DECLARE @position INT=PATINDEX(CONCAT('%[',@toBeReplaced,']%'),SUBSTRING(@word,2,8000))+1;

SELECT STUFF(@word,@position,1,TRANSLATE(SUBSTRING(@word,@position,1),@toBeReplaced,@replaceWith));
```

The idea in short:

- We define your translate parameters.
- We find the position using `PATINDEX()` *behind* the first character.
- Now we can use `STUFF()` to replace exactly one character at the given position by its translation.

For the next time: It would help a lot if you'd provided some samples with the expected result.

**UPDATE**

Using this at a tabular result, you can avoid the declared variable and do this *inline*:

```
DECLARE @WordTable TABLE(SomeText varchar(8));
INSERT INTO @WordTable VALUES('truth'),('loveable');

DECLARE @toBeReplaced VARCHAR(10)='abeilost';
DECLARE @replaceWith VARCHAR(10)='@83!10$+';
```

--the new query

```
SELECT STUFF(wt.SomeText,pos,1,TRANSLATE(SUBSTRING(wt.SomeText,pos,1),@toBeReplaced,@replaceWith))
FROM @WordTable wt
CROSS APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX(CONCAT('%[',@toBeReplaced,']%'),SUBSTRING(wt.SomeText,2,8000))+1) A(pos);
```

Comment: Yeah that works in my newer copy of SQL, but I went back in the end to the case statement as it turns out production copy is OOLLDD. I like scalability etc of this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PATINDEX('[a-z][abeilost]', @Word)
```

Is returning 0. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) 0 means not found. The reason it is not being found it that your search criteria is for 2 characters only, the first being a single character which matches `[a-z]`, and the second being a single character which matches `[abeilost]`. If you want to allow more characters you need to extend the search expression e.g.

```
SELECT PATINDEX('[a-z][abeilost]%', @Word)
```

Although I expect that isn't doing what you want as I imagine you want to repeat the specified characters any number of times which isn't possible with `PATINDEX`.

Comment: This got me to the answer, but the issue was twofold - again from the docco: "Wildcard characters can be used; however, the % character must come before and follow pattern (except when you search for first or last characters)." Because there was neither a '%' character at the beginning or end, it was always returning 0, but adding one to the end meant that if the *exactly second* character wasn't matchable, it still returned 0. Add this to your answer and you've got my tick.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying? What is your solution? I added the percentage at the end and it worked?

Comment: Adding a % at the end would work if the second character is replaceable, but consider “truth” which should ultimately return `tru+h` - this would mean replacing the 4th character, but `SELECT PATINDEX(‘[a-z][abeilost]%’,’truth’)` will return 0. Needs a % at the start of the pattern too.